# How to disable control click events when modal dialog is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

As per my knowledge all the input controls will be disabled, once I open modal dialog in jquery. But still i will be able to click on button,div etc controls. Is there any way in jquery I can disable all the interactions once the modal dialog is opened.

Comment: Does the modal dialog not do this automatically? (If it lets you interact with the other controls it isn't modal, so...?)

Comment: I just tried it in small application, It doesnt do it automatically. Though it disables all the input controls(text,textarea,select,...)

Answer (score -2):

You have to overlay the entire page with a div so that all the controls will be laid behind the overlay div.

```
<div class="overlay" style="z-index: 1001; width: 1440px; height: 504px; "></div>
.overlay {
background: #AAA 
opacity: .3;
filter: Alpha(Opacity=30);
}
```

More info: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal.html